# Add local gem to the project in Ruby on Rails without downloading it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems

I am studying Ruby on Rails these days.

My first project requires **devise** gem and it was installed during the bundle install and added to the local storage in Ubuntu System(path is */home/silvi/.rvm/gems*).

I created a new project and did some tutorials. At first I didn't need **devise** gem, but now I need **devise** gem to test authentication. I want to add **devise** gem from local storage with its dependencies.

**How can I handle this with bundle/gem command?**

Comment: Maybe reading [the devise docs.](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#getting-started) could be a good start? If it's something else you're looking for, please explain further.

Comment: `bundle install --local` - Do not attempt to fetch gems remotely and use the gem cache instead - I don't know why you would do this in development when learning though unless bandwith is a real issue. https://bundler.io/bundle_install.html

Comment: However its really unclear what you are asking - if you have already installed the gem in the currect version bundler will not attempt to download it again anyways?